# Switching an app from displaying one quote at random to all in a grid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I previously built an app (my first rails app) designed to display a single quote from the db at random on screen (and a different one on each refresh). I'm now aiming to refactor that app to display all of the quotes (paginated, I guess) in a grid format.

The catch is that I'm uncertain how to pull all of the quotes to display on the page instead of just one at random. In the controller, I previously had:

```
def index
    @quote = Quote.order("RANDOM()").first
end
```

Would it be something like this?

```
def index
    Quote.each do
      @quote = Quote.order("RANDOM()")
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you try  "RAND()" instead of "RANDOM()" ?

Comment: I can try it, but the issue I'm having doesn't have to do with the RANDOM() not working (that works fine). I just don't know how to rewrite the controller to bring back ALL of the quotes instead of the first one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller

```
def index 
  @quotes = Quote.order("RANDOM()")
end
```

Then in your view

```
-@quotes.each do
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Keiran, that got me there!

Answer (score 3):

Type this in your controller:

```
def index
   @quotes = Quote.order("RAND()").all
end
```

In your view type this:

```
<% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
   <%= quote.id
   <%= quote.X   <---------REPLACE X for the column to show
   <%= quote.X   <---------REPLACE X for the column to show
<% end%>
```